# Java - reading values from a file?

Tags: java

So I'm attempting to build a graph and find the shortest path between two objects. To build the graph I'm reading names and values from an input file:

```
Location1 0 0 0 
Location2 5 0 0 
Location3 5 5 0 
Location4 0 5 0
```

My question is how do I read in these values? Here's what I'm doing for my main method:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // You can test your program with something like this.
      In in = new In( args[0] );
      int T = in.readInt();
      for (int t=1; t<=T; t++) {
         System.out.println("Case " + t + ":") ;
         Edge w = new Edge( in );
      }
   }
```

And then in another method where I find the coordinates of each location, store each point in a hash table, and then move on to the next line:

```
public In coordinates(in){
    while (in.hasNext()){
        String location = in.next();
        String point1 = args[1];
        String point2 = args[2];
        String point3 = args[3];
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out is how I add these values to a has table and then always associate the location with these coordinates. I want to find the shortest path using Floyd - Warshall's algorithm which I can do like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            dist[i][j] = Math.min(dist[i][j], dist[i][k] + dist[k][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I want these values to go into a 2d array called dist but I don't know how to assign these values to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a bufferedReader and a File reader

```
File file = new File(replace with file location);
FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    //process line will be in the format of a String
}
br.close();
```

line will be equal to what the current line in the file is. It will keep reading the file till the file till the end

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest you to make a custom object say `Location` and then use a `HashMap` to retain the linking information.

Once you read the complete input and prepare the `HashMap` you can iterate it and do your calculations.

See the below code snippet:

**Location Class:**

```
public class Location 
{
    private String location;
    private int point1;
    private int point2;
    private int point3;

    public Location(String location, int point1, int point2, int point3) {
        this.location = location;
        this.point1 = point1;
        this.point2 = point2;
        this.point3 = point3;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location= location;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return this.location;
    }

    public void setPoint1(int point1) {
        this.point1 = point1;
    }

    public int getPoint1() {
        return this.point1;
    }

    public void setPoint2(int point2) {
        this.point2 = point2;
    }

    public int getPoint2() {
        return this.point2;
    }

    public void setPoint3(int point3) {
        this.point3 = point3;
    }

    public int getPoint3() {
        return this.point3;
    }
}
```

**Main Class:**

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Foo f = new Foo(); 
        f.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        Map<String,Location> locationMap = new HashMap<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = null;
        while(in.hasNext()) {
            line = in.nextLine();
            String[] split = line.split(" ");
            locationMap.put(split[0],new Location(split[0],Integer.parseInt(split[1]),
                            Integer.parseInt(split[2]),Integer.parseInt(split[3])));
        }

        /* Iterate locationMap and do your calculations */
    }
}
```

Here I have used `System.in` to read the input from console. You can replace it to take input from any desired File.